# Deployment difference between karaf feature bundle and karaf bundle:install

Tags: apache-karaf, pax-exam

How below both deployments are different

```
<feature name="my-base-bundles" version="${project.version}">
        <bundle start-level="86">mvn:com.my.osgi/mycomponent/0.0.1</bundle>
</feature>
```

and

```
bundle:install -s mvn:com.my.osgi/mycomponent/0.0.1
```

what i observed is deploying with feature shows service:list like

```
[com.my.osgi.mycomponent]
-----------------------------------------------------
instance.name = mycomponent.3c2c91a5-4c28-46c3-a08e-1470192ef353
 service.bundleid = 76
 service.factoryPid = com.my.osgi.mycomponent
 service.id = 397
 service.pid = com.my.osgi.mycomponent.3c2c91a5-4c28-46c3-a08e-1470192ef353
 service.scope = bundle
```

and by deploying with bundle:install

```
[org.apache.felix.ipojo.Factory]
--------------------------------
 component.class = com.my.osgi.mycomponent
 component.description = factory name="com.my.osgi.mycomponent" bundle="77" state="valid" implementation-class="com.my.osgi.mycomponent"
        requiredhandlers list="[org.apache.felix.ipojo:properties, org.apache.felix.ipojo:callback, org.apache.felix.ipojo:provides, org.apache.felix.ipojo:architect
ure]"
        missinghandlers list="[]"
        provides specification="com.my.osgi.mycomponent"
        inherited interfaces="[com.my.osgi.mycomponent]" superclasses="[]"
 component.providedServiceSpecifications = [com.my.osgi.mycomponent]
 factory.name = com.my.osgi.mycomponent
 factory.state = 1
 service.bundleid = 77
 service.id = 153
 service.pid = com.my.osgi.mycomponent
 service.scope = singleton
```

it work fine but my pax-exam tests are getting failed as after installing i look for service

```
serviceReferences = this.bundleContext.getServiceReferences("com.my.osgi.mycomponent", filter);
```

how i should deploy in pax-exam so i can access services like feature deployments?

Answer (score 0):

The start level is different between the two installations.

- Feature installation: start level = 86 **explicitly**
- bundle installation: start level = defaut = 90 **implicitly**

So try to install the bundle with the some start-level value